# How to implement the gifplayer jQuery plugin in Shopify?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, shopify

**Desired Behaviour**

I want to implement the jQuery `gifplayer` plugin in shopify:

https://github.com/rubentd/gifplayer

**Current Behaviour**

Firebug errors:

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings observed the loading of a resource at data:application/javascript;base64...
```

And I can see the GIF button over the specified image, but clicking it does not cause the gif to stop and start.

**What I've Tried**

**01)**  I've applied the `gifplayer` class to an image.

**02)**  I've uploaded `jquery.gifplayer.js` as an `asset`.

**03)**  I've uploaded `gifplayer.css` as an `asset`.

**04)**  And `jquery-1.9.0.min.js` was already an asset.

**05)**  In `theme.liquid` I've added this in the `<head>`.

```
{{ 'gifplayer.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
<!-- jquery was already being called in -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- BEGIN custom gifplayer -->
{{ 'jquery.gifplayer.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
$('.gifplayer').gifplayer();
});
</script>
<!-- END custom gifplayer -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I didn't realise you needed to apply the class `gifplayer` to a static `png` file of the same name.

**HTML**

```
{{ 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/n/nnnn/nnnn/t/n/assets/my_static_img.png' | img_tag: 'hi', 'gifplayer'}}
```

**theme.liquid**

```
{{ 'gifplayer.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
// jQuery call comes before gifplayer.js
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{{ 'jquery.gifplayer.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
$('.gifplayer').gifplayer();
});
</script>
```

**Uploaded Assets**

```
my_great_gif.png
my_great_gif.gif
jquery.gifplayer.js
gifplayer.css
```